# Missing property "JMSXDeliveryCount" from ActiveMQ message

Tags: jboss, jms, activemq-classic

As per link - http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-message-properties.html
Message should have "**JMSXDeliveryCount**" used for Number of attempts to send the message

When checked from jconsole for message properties, it's missing though other Jms supported property like "**JMSXGroupID**" & "**JMSXGroupSeq**" is available

[image]

Note: -

1. I have used standard activemq-5.14.2 setup and starting it up from win64
2. JBoss Server is used

Comment: can you able to see JMSXDeliveryCount property on mq web console.

Comment: Try hawtio console.

Comment: @Nir Nope, Though the issue got resolved by accessing JMS message in code, our code was parsing JMS to Client Specific Message pojo..and missed out on property. Still, not sure why activemq console didn't show the property

Comment: As below answer already explained it that this property will be visible on mq console only if message is redelivered to consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JMSXDeliveryCount property is only available when the message has been delivered once and then re-dispatched (session recover etc).  If the delivery count of the message is zero then there will be no JMSXDeliveryCount present in the returned set from getPropertyNames() or the like.

Answer (score 0):

There is a message property named JMSXDeliveryCount that indicates how many times the message has been delivered. Section 3.5.11 of the JMS 2. 0 spec says this about JMSXDeliveryCount:

When a client receives a message the mandatory JMS-defined message property JMSXDeliveryCount will be set to the number of times the message has been delivered. The first time a message is received it will be set to 1, so a value of 2 or more means the message has been redelivered.

If the JMSRedelivered message header value is set then the JMSXDeliveryCount property must always be 2 or more. See section 3.4.7 “JMSRedelivered” for more information about the JMSRedelivered message header,

The purpose of the JMSXDeliveryCount property is to allow consuming applications to identify whether a particular message is being repeatedly redelivered and take appropriate action.

The value of the JMSXDeliveryCount property is not guaranteed to be exactly correct. The JMS provider is not expected to persist this value to ensure that its value is not lost in the event of a failure.